# QtCreator and `$$files(*.cpp)`. how to reload file list?

Tags: qt-creator, qmake

In my qmake-pro-file, I use something like `SOURCES = $$files(*.cpp)` which expresses exactly what I want and works great when I do `qmake && make`. However, when I work with QtCreator and when I add or rename some file, how can I get QtCreator to update the file list? I currently must restart QtCreator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the only ways you can force qt-creator to re-parse the `pro` file is by either touching the `pro` file (i.e. `$ touch project.pro`), or by re-saving the `pro` file (i.e. by adding a random space somewhere, removing it again and saving the file).

Comment: So to be clear, the error you are seeing is that when you are compiling the project the Makefiles don't include the just-added/renamed files?

Comment: Or, if you are referring to the file list in the project pane, just re-save the `project.pro` file (i.e. add a random space somewhere, remove it again, press save), then qt-creator will reload the file list.

Comment: I'm referring to the project pane in QtCreator. Thanks for the trick, that saves me from restarting QtCreator. But it still doesn't really feel like a real solution to the problem.

Comment: As I've written in the edited answer, you could also touch the pro file. Beyond that, I don't know of any more elegant solutions I'm afraid.